# How data write in xlsx file using xlsxwriter?

Tags: python, excel, file-handling, xlsxwriter, file-writing

I am writing in excel file using python xlsxwriter module.

```
import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(r"E:\python_SQL\bedroom number\2.xlsx")
sheet = workbook.add_worksheet("raviraj")
sheet.write(0, 0, "RAVIRAJ")
```

code is executing but no sheet is getting added in excel nor data in a cell.

**I am using windows 10 os and python 3.6. What I am missing?**

Answer (score 1):

You need to close the workbook as well. At the end of your code, add

```
workbook.close()
```

Comment: Perfect answer. You are missing the line to save and close your file. Check [this example](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/tutorial01.html) in documentation.